# Integrate New relic using carthage package manager

Tags: ios, swift, newrelic, carthage

Is there any way i can integrate New Relic sdk into my iOS project using carthage package manager? I don't want to use cocoa pods to do this since i am already using carthage package manager in my project.

Answer (score 2):

### Fetch the package via Carthage

To use Carthage there are a few steps. First inside of your `Carthage/` Directory add a file called `new_relic.json` and add this to it:

```
{
  "6.7.0": "https://download.newrelic.com/ios_agent/NewRelic_iOS_Agent_6.7.0.zip"
}
```

Then in your `Cartfile` add this line:

`binary "./Carthage/new_relic.json" == 6.7.0`

Finally run `carthage update --platform ios`

### Integrate New Relic

1. After you run your update command and you have the package, go to the `general` tab and add all of these packages to the `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section:

[image: Linked Frameworks and Libraries]

2. Add a bridging header to your project and add this line of code

`#import "NewRelicAgent/NewRelic.h"`

3. Then add this script to your build phases section:

```
 SCRIPT=`/usr/bin/find "${SRCROOT}" -name newrelic_postbuild.sh | head -n 1`
 /bin/sh "${SCRIPT}" "Your token here"
```

4. And this line of code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

`NewRelic.start(withApplicationToken:"Your Token Here")`